# probleme with Firebase Android pagination

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I'm building an app which will show Posts stored on firebase. The list of Post needs to be paginated fetching most recent 10 posts at a time.

[image: image firebase database]

Here is the methode to load post:

```
private void readsposts(){

        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts");
        reference.keepSynced(true);

        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                     postList.clear();

                for(DataSnapshot snapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                    Post post = snapshot.getValue(Post.class);
                    for(String id:followingList){

                        if(post.getPublisher()!=null && post.getPublisher().equals(id)){
                            postList.add(post);
                            indication.stopShimmer();
                            indication.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    }

                    if(post.getPublisher()!=null && post.getPublisher().equals(firebaseUser.getUid())){
                        postList.add(post);
                        //stop shimmer
                        indication.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        indication.stopShimmer();
                     }
                }
                postAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
}
```

But above code retrieves entire list of posts instead of limited posts. How can pagination be implemented?

Comment: If you search for [`firebase-realtime-database` pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-realtime-database%5D+pagination), you'll find that this topic has been covered many times before. I recommend reading up on some of those answers.

Comment: Can you do me a proposition with this methode please

Answer (score 0):

[when you fetch data at a location in your database, you also retrieve all of its child nodes.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data#best_practices_for_data_structure)

(because you read "Posts")

so if you Advance record your post key ,otherwise you will download data

so you can new a table of Contents to stockpile your post key

Comment: i have a problem i got 5000 post and got heavy and makes the application slow i want to know how to load the posts 10 into 10 so on ... i'm a debutant please how can pagination in recyclerview with Firebase database